# didn't I or hadn't I?

Tags: tag-questions

> 1. I had to try, didn't I?

or

> 2. I had to try, hadn't I?

Which one is correct? If both sound awkward, could you please tell me the correct answer?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern standard English, "have" in "have to" is generally treated as a lexical verb, not as an auxiliary: eg. "I didn't have to try" (cf. the less idiomatic *"I haven't to try").

So in this case you need to add the dummy auxiliary "do" and "have" cannot be in the question tag:

"I had to try, didn't I". ✅